# How to paint using brush with particular area...

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

[image]

I want to fill each and every part with different colours like circle with other colour and each leave with different colour and stick with different colours. I have bunch of colours. You can fidn similar apps like Toonia Color book on apple app store...

I am unable to get bounds of particular part in image.

I searched a whole day before writing this question. Every one is saying just look for flood fill and Quick Fill algorithms but i am not able to solve this problem.

Comment: Why are you "not able to solve this problem"? Do you mean, you don't understand how to make flood fill work?

Comment: I don't want to fill whole area at one time

Comment: I want that user should fill that area with his/her finger similar to app... toonia color book... just download it...if you have any confusion

Comment: U are saying that i just took each and every part as different view and then color them with brush....But i don't want to do this... if i would have 100 images.. then my app size would be too much...

Comment: Could you kindly suggest me one simple and best way for doing the same thing...which i mentioned above.

Comment: No, I've never written a painting app like this before. However, as a developer I wouldn't want to get someone else to write my app for me. Put some work in before you ask. I imagine using the same flood fill algorithm you could limit where the painting takes place. This is part of what being a developer is about.

Comment: Thant above line every one is used to say... when they are not in trouble...:)

Comment: @Alfa do you get any solution for this? I want to make same like this but getting results is every where flood fill. Do you have any link/sample code to share for this?

Comment: @Niks Yes i resolved it, the best way is to Use SVG and then get each and every layer from same... then you can easily find the CAShapelayer by using SVGKit library.... then can easily color on same by cropping the context according to the path of layer.. .CHEERS HAPPY CODING :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Toonia Colorbook this is done using vector graphics and masks. Every shape is described as a bezier curve that masks a drawing layer.

check out [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) and [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CALayer) for further details

Comment: I tried to use this but it's not working as... my brush size is big and if someone move touches very fastly it just goes beyond its cgpath.....